# Flutter FrontEnd Solution Loop ListView.builder - Offline ChatBot

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

so I'm working on my first app. I want to build a ChatBot that handels everything by himself (offline and no ai!): It should be a normal conversation with Questions/Answers/Responses. All strings are saved in a JSON File. The answer is bound to the response (answer one = response one). If it helps: JSON looks like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "messages": ["Heyy!", "How are you...", "You look a little bit strange "],
      "answer": ["That's not nice...", "Do I look that bad?", "Thank you?"],
      "response": ["Sorry, I had a bad day...", "No, why...oh", "F yourself!"]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "messages": ["By the way, where do you come from?", "Would like to know you....", "I'm new here in town "],
      "answers": ["OK"],
      "response": ["Is that your answer?"]
    }]
```

And my answer comes from an responsive button.
My problem is, that I dont know how to loop this all after the first block. This is my FrontEnd Code:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String characterName;
  const TestPage({Key? key, required this.characterName}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TestListPageState createState() => _TestListPageState();}
class _TestListPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  late String characterName;
  late Future<dynamic> chatlistv2;
  late List<String> messages;
  late List<String> answers;
  late List<String> responses;
  int selectedAnswerIndex = -1;
  int messagesindex = 0;
  dynamic datav2;
  void _refreshData(messagesindex) async {
    final datav2 = await JsonConnector.readJsonChatv2Test();
    setState(() {
      messages = List<String>.from(datav2['data'][messagesindex]['messages']);
      answers = List<String>.from(datav2['data'][messagesindex]['answer']);
      responses = List<String>.from(datav2['data'][messagesindex]['response']);
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    characterName = widget.characterName;
    _refreshData(messagesindex);
  }
  void onAnswerButtonClicked(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedAnswerIndex = index;
    });
    _refreshData(messagesindex);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        title: Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                  'assets/Profiles/$characterName/$characterName.jpg'),
              radius: 20,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                characterName,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/Wallpaper/Wallpaper.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: selectedAnswerIndex >= 0
                    ? messages.length + 1
                    : messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == messages.length) {
                    return buildMessage(responses[se`your text`lectedAnswerIndex]);
                  } else {
                    return buildMessage(messages[index]);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            if (selectedAnswerIndex < 0)
              Row(
                children: answers.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
                  final index = entry.key;
                  final answer = entry.value;
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => onAnswerButtonClicked(index),
                      child: Text(answer),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget buildMessage(String message) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Text(
            message,
            style: const TextStyle(`your text`
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 22,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope to find some help here...Maybe I need to build a listview in the listview..?`

Comment: Can you clarify your problem detailed way? Especially this sentence "My problem is, that I dont know how to loop this all after the first block."

Comment: Yeah sure! The App displays the messages of the first "block" ["Heyy!", "How are you...", "You look a little bit strange "] in an "Telegram Chat Style". After that, a row appers, at the bottom of the screen with all the answers as buttons. After the button click, the responds appers. "That's not nice..."->Sorry, I had a bad day...  The block is done after this, got my response from the "bot". But I want start the next block after this, so that it looks like an conversation between me and a bot. It does not necessarily need to be a loop logic, if there is a better solutions I take it ^^